# hadoop installation multinode cluster formation on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hadoop

Can hadoop (pseudo) Multinode cluster setup be installed on ubuntu 14.04 without using virtual machine player?

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04. I dont have windows on my system. Is there any way by which I can install (pseudo) multinode hadoop cluster on my laptop. I have a lot of tutorials either they use VMware on windows or even if they use ubuntu they use other laptops as well for multinode.

Comment: There are quite a few examples and tutorials on doing it using docker. Perhaps take a look at some of those.

Comment: Yes It can be done using docker, here the example https://github.com/kiwenlau/hadoop-cluster-docker